# Selenium SessionNotCreatedException in Jenkins Due to 'No space left on device (os error 28) at path "/tmp/rust_mozprofileO0WZJN"'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid, selenium-firefoxdriver

While attempting to run Selenium through Jenkins, I encountered the following error:

```java
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. 
Message: No space left on device (os error 28) at path "/tmp/rust_mozprofileO0WZJN"
Build info: 
version: '4.3.0', 
revision: 'a4995e2c09*' 
System info: 
host: 'pic-01-vm-nubo11picmolecule02-01-selenium.novalocal', 
ip: '172.18.0.39', 
os.name: 'Linux', 
os.arch: 'amd64', 
os.version: '5.14.0-284.18.1.el9_2.x86_64', 
java.version: '17.0.8'
```

As a troubleshooting step, I tried to modify the path set for the driver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ubuntu "No space left on device" but there is tons of space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706398/ubuntu-no-space-left-on-device-but-there-is-tons-of-space)

Comment: Have you actually tried to check if there was space left on your device ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message "No space left on device (os error 28)" is pretty straightforward.

The messaage indicates that the `/tmp` directory does not have enough space left. Selenium uses the /tmp directory to create temporary profiles when it runs tests, as indicated in the error message `(os error 28) at path "/tmp/rust_mozprofileO0WZJN"`.

Carry out command `df -h` to see the disk usage of your file systems and check the usage of the `/tmp` directory. If this is indeed teh case, see if you can free up some space.

There is another alternative, as you are using a Firefox browser, you can set the `options` property to make Selenium use a different path.

The question does not indicate what Selenium language you are using, but below is an illustration for Chrome & Firefox, using Java or Python

Chrome - Java

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/directory");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
}
```

Chrome Python

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/directory")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Firefox Java

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.addPreference("browser.download.dir", "/path/to/your/directory");
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    }
}
```

Firefox Python

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.profile = "/path/to/your/directory"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

The above examples should redirect Selenium to store it's temporary profiles to the path specified other than `/tmp`

**N.B.**
Make sure that the directory specified exists and that Selenium has the necessary permissions to write to it.